# Sending an email using variable as email body

Tags: python, selenium, smtplib

Using a simple webscraper I am able to return the contents of what I'm looking for into variables in my script `content : content1`.

For some reason, I can't get the contents to display in the email body.

I have tried using `message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'text'))` `message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'html'))` that made no difference. Also imported `time` module as I thought a delay in the script might help but it did not.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import smtplib, ssl
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import time

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users\James\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get('https://www.skysports.com/football/news')


FootballHeadlines = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("news-list__headline-link")
for elem in FootballHeadlines:
    print(elem.text)
    print(elem.get_attribute("href"))

content  = (elem.text)
content1 = (elem.get_attribute("href"))


sender_address = 'some@email'
sender_password = '**********'
receiver_email = 'someother@email'


message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = sender_address
message['Subject'] = 'Latest on Football' 
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
session.starttls()
session.login(sender_address, sender_password) 
mail_content = message.as_string(content)
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'html'))
session.sendmail(sender_address, sender_address, mail_content)
```

Comment: Try `print(elem.get_attribute('innerHTML'))`. It will get the headline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem wasn't in sending the email. For some reason, selenium wasn't able to get the text out of the elements it found. I used beautiful soup instead. The following code works.

```py
import bs4 as Bs
import smtplib, ssl
from selenium import webdriver
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

DRIVER_PATH = 'D:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get('https://www.skysports.com/football/news')

page_src = Bs.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
links = page_src.findAll("a", {"class" : "news-list__headline-link"})

content = ''
for link in links:
    content +='\n'+link.text
    
print(content)

sender_address = 'yatint5@gmail.com'
sender_password = 'ehdqxsdsuyuicupa'
receiver_email = sender_address


message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = sender_address
message['Subject'] = 'Latest on Football' 
message.attach(MIMEText(content, 'plain'))


session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
session.starttls()
session.login(sender_address, sender_password) 
mail_content = message.as_string(content)
print(mail_content)
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'html'))
session.sendmail(sender_address, sender_address, mail_content)
```

[image]

PS: I have revoked the app-password...